# Websocket server with socket.io doesnt work

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I want to make a socket.io websocket server but it doesnt work. What's wrong with my script?

Script:

http://pastebin.com/eJ4Eny0w

Answer (score 0):

Place `server.listen(...)` at the very end. Also, your declaration of `socket` (`=require(...)`) seems off. Change this to `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

Code is:

```
var server = require( 'http' ).createServer();
server.listen( 4444 );
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var io = socket.listen( server );   
console.log('Started!');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected');
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('Debug!');
    });
});
```

Should be:

```
var server = require( 'http' ).createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  
console.log('Started!');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected');
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('Debug!');
    });
});
server.listen( 4444 );
```

Comment: sry for the late answere but it now returns the error: undefined with the new script too